# Joda DateTime conversion locale

Tags: java, jodatime

Im trying to convert milliseconds in Joda DateTime.
Millis are **1338501600000**
I used online converter and other libraries and all result are that **1338501600000** millis is **Fri Jun 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)**

In Joda the result is: **2012-05-31T22:00:00.000Z**

Why?

---

Resolved:

```
long millis = 1338501600000;
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2:00");
DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
dtz.setDefault(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(tz));
DateTime rightDate = new DateTime(millis,dtz);
```

Comment: `Z` at the end of the date is GMT+0000, so 2 hours difference with GMT+0200.

Answer (score 2):

Those are the same dates. If you subtract 2 hours from your GMT+0200 date, you obtain the Joda result, which is in the GMT timezone.

A single date (instant in time) can be represented in different ways as a String, and the representation depends on the timezone used to generate this representation.

Comment: And how can I set the GMT in JodaTime?

Comment: Use http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29 and http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#forOffsetHours%28int%29

Comment: thanks!!! but is possible to set the library use by default GMT+2 and not use everytime the formatter?

Comment: You haven't shown us how you construct and display your dates. But I guess http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#setDefault%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29 is what you're looking for. I'm by no means a joda-time expert, but simply reading the javadoc would teach you lots of things. Why don't you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Note that Fri Jun 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0200 and 2012-05-31T22:00:00.000Z are the same moment in time, only the first one is displayed in the time zone GMT+0200 and the second one in UTC (which is what the Z indicates).